# Get the deviation of values between two dates in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the data in the following format :

```
run_date    test_alias  test_value
12/23/2014    1           12
11/22/2014    1           5
1/20/2015     1           7
2/20/2015     1           9

12/19/2014    2           12
2/19/2015     2           12.5
1/18/2015     2           13
11/17/2014    2           12.7

2/13/2015     3           4
1/13/2015     3           5
12/13/2014    3           7
11/13/2014    3           8
```

How can i get the id for records where in the deviation is between 2 and 4 for the last 3 months from today's date .In this case id 3 and 1 should be picked up since 
For id 3 the last 3 month value is 4 ,5 and 7  .So deviaton in this case is 7-4 =3 which is between 2 and 4
For id 1 the value for last three months are 9,7 and 12  i.e 12- 9 = 3

Any help would be really great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT test_alias, max(test_value) - min(test_value) AS deviation
  FROM my_table
  WHERE run_date >= Dateadd(month, -3, Getdate())
  GROUP BY test_alias
  HAVING (max(test_value) - min(test_value)) BETWEEN 2 AND 4
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without aggregate functions

Comment: It goes more complicated but you could try something like `SELECT DISTINCT test_alias
FROM my_table WHERE test_alias IN (SELECT test_alias FROM my_table mt1 WHERE mt1.run_date >  Dateadd(month, -3, Getdate()) AND mt1.test_value >= my_table.test_value + 2) AND test_alias NOT IN (SELECT test_alias FROM my_table mt1 WHERE mt1.run_date >  Dateadd(month, -3, Getdate()) AND mt1.test_value >= my_table.test_value + 5) AND run_date >= Dateadd(month, -3, Getdate()) my_table ORDER BY test_alias, test_value`

Comment: how can i use you first query to find the % of change between max and min  in the same query

Comment: You can just add a column `(max(test_value) - min(test_value)) / max(test_value) * 100`.